# How to transpose XSLT from Rows Into Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am seeking advice on the corrext XSLT method to transpose XML output from rows to there correct logical elements.

As an example i have the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report>
    <Field>GetMembershipDetails</Field>
    <Row>
        <Item>MembershipID</Item>
        <Item>MemberNumber</Item>
        <Item>MembershipStatus</Item>
        <Item>BenefitStartDate</Item>
        <Item>BenefitEndDate</Item>
        <Item>MembershipStartDate</Item>
        <Item>MembershipEndDate</Item>
        <Item>MembershpResignationDate</Item>
        <Item>MembershipAnniversaryDate</Item>
        <Item>MembershipType</Item>
        <Item>ContactId</Item>
        <Item>ContactTitle</Item>
        <Item>ContactFirstName</Item>
        <Item>ContactLastName</Item>
        <Item>ContactGender</Item>
        <Item>ContactDateOfBirth</Item>
        <Item>ContactEmployeeNumber</Item>
        <Item>ContactEmployeDateJoined</Item>
        <Item>ContactCorporateAccountNo</Item>
        <Item>ContactEmailAddress</Item>
        <Item>ContactPostalStreet</Item>
        <Item>ContactPostalCity</Item>
        <Item>ContactPostalState</Item>
        <Item>ContactPostalPostCode</Item>
        <Item>ContactResidentialStreet</Item>
        <Item>ContactResidentialState</Item>
        <Item>ContactResidentialCity</Item>
        <Item>ContactResidentialPostCode</Item>
        <Item>ContactResidentialCountry</Item>
        <Item>ContactType</Item>
        <Item>ProductName</Item>
        <Item>ProductDescription</Item>
        <Item>ProductType</Item>
        <Item>ProductAmount</Item>
        <Item>MembershipProductID</Item>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Item>8</Item>
        <Item>A2000</Item>
        <Item>Current</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>Current</Item>
        <Item>109</Item>
        <Item>Mr</Item>
        <Item>John</Item>
        <Item>Foley</Item>
        <Item>Male</Item>
        <Item>10/09/2014</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>0</Item>
        <Item>jfoley@test.com</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>0</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>Australia</Item>
        <Item>Primary</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>No Value</Item>
        <Item>0</Item>
        <Item>8</Item>
    </Row>
</Report>
```

Which should become something like

```
<Table>
<Row>
<MembershipID>8</MembershipID>
...
...
</Row>
</Table>
```

Or Even

```
<Table>
<Row>
<Column name="MembershipID">8</Column>
...
</Row>
</Table>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option is definitely preferable. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="column-name" match="Row[1]/Item" use="count(preceding-sibling::Item)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Report/Row[position() > 1]">
            <Row>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <Column name="{key('column-name', count(preceding-sibling::Item))}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Column>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--

Or perhaps you prefer changing:

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="Item[not(.='No Value')]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer above is correct for the second option.

This is the result if you decide to do the first option.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>
    <!-- Select the heading names into a variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="headingNames" select="//Row[1]/Item"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Report/Row">
            <!--Check to make sure that we only select the second row onwards (as first row is the headings)--> 
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
            <Row>
                <xsl:variable name="rowVal" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$rowVal/Item">
                    <xsl:variable name="currentPos" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:element name="{$headingNames[$currentPos]}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </Row>
            </xsl:if>           
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you decide to do the first option, you should keep in mind that (1) this will fail if any of the item names (in the first row of the input) happens to be an invalid element name, and (2) subsequent processing of the result will become more difficult.